# ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table using UNION and CASE postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

i am trying to make a `VIEW` using `UNION` and i want make a `column` dynamic and for this I am using the `CASE`.

Follow code:

```
CREATE VIEW exportU
  AS
    SELECT
      email_user
      cast(null as int) as blabla1
      cast(null as int) as blabla2,
      cast(null as varchar) as blabla3
    FROM table1 a
UNION
    SELECT
      cast(null as varchar) as email_user
      cast(null as int) as blabla1
      cast(null as int) as blabla2,
      cast(null as varchar) as blabla3
    FROM table2 b
UNION
    SELECT
      cast(null as varchar) as email_user
      intColumn,
      intColumn2,
      new_position_id,
      (CASE WHEN a.email_user = c.filled_by THEN a.email_user ELSE c.filled_by END) as "fill"
    FROM table3 c
```

and i receive that error:

> ```
> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "a"
> LINE 156:    (CASE WHEN a.email_user = c.filled_by THEN a.email_user ELSE c.filled...
> ```

I dont know why, i am using `alias` after of the name of the table..

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Pay close attention to your commas.

Comment: extra commas before `FROM` and missing coma after `email_user`

Comment: sorry, it is because i edited it.

Comment: Also in that last select your table1 alias from the first select isn't going to be in scope. You need a join.

Comment: in the real code it doesn't exist, i was editing the query and forget remove it

Comment: @Shawn join not work for me, just a union, but a i need to make a column dynamic like this...

Comment: @Jota . . . Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want would all help.  You might be surprised to learn that a non-working query does not necessary provide much useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be carefull about commas and about type and number of columns. They have to match on all unions.

Here is an example on how I make it work:

I have to create a dummy column on the first select because the last one had an extra column. Also every column need to be same type

[**SQL DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5647b/1)

```
CREATE VIEW exportU
  AS
    SELECT
      cast(null as varchar) as email_user,
      cast(null as int) as blabla1,
      cast(null as int) as blabla2,
      cast(null as varchar) as blabla3,
      0 as dummy
    FROM table1 a
UNION
    SELECT
      cast(null as varchar) as email_user,
      cast(null as int) as blabla1,
      cast(null as int) as blabla2,
      cast(null as varchar) as blabla3,
      0 as dummy
    FROM table1 b
UNION
    SELECT
      cast(null as varchar) as email_user,
      cast(null as int) as blabla1,
      cast(null as int) as blabla2,
     '0' as new_position_id, -- blabla3
      (CASE WHEN 0 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) as "fill"
    FROM table1 c
```

And this case is redundant. You can replace it with just `c.filled_by` because if they are equal then doesnt matter which one you assign

```
 CASE WHEN a.email_user = c.filled_by THEN a.email_user ELSE c.filled_by END
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for answer.. but i want the value of the column not 0 or 1, do you understand ?

Comment: Yes but I don't have to data structure, so I have to use something. You can put the value of the column instead, as long you have same type as the dummy column on the first select should work. But as I explain at the end of the answer your CASE isn't need it.